# as3 reset the 'numPressed' function

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm quite new to as3 so this may be pretty obvious to most of you out there :P
I'm using the numPressed function (which counts the mouse clicks) and need to reset the mouse clicks after the 6th click...
This is what the code looks like:

```
var numPressed:Number = 0;
any_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, countUp);
function countUp(evt:MouseEvent):void {
numPressed++;

if (numPressed == 1) {
any_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
else if (numPressed == 2) {
any_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

else if (numPressed == 3) {
any_mc.gotoAndPlay(3);
}

else if (numPressed == 4) {
any_mc.gotoAndPlay(4);
}

else if (numPressed == 5) {
any_mc.gotoAndPlay(5);
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `if(numPressed >= 6) numPressed = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Taurayi said but also you could clean your function up a little also like this.

```
function countUp(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    any_mc.gotoAndPlay(numPressed++);

    if(numPressed > 5)
        numPressed = 1;
}
```